# remove vim statusline for horizontal splits with laststatus already set to 0

Tags: statusline

I was wondering if the statusline between horizontal splits can be removed. Maybe it can be replaced by command line?

Comment: not possible. As soon as you have several windows, you won't be able to remove the statusline. You can make it invisible, by setting it to empty and using the Normal highlighting group, but you won't be able to remove it completely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not remove the statusline, if you have more than two horizontal splits, But you can change the highlight of statusline, just make it same as your normal content.

for example:

`let &statusline='%#Normal# '`

here is my vim screenshort, and it have two splits, vim file on the top, and markdown is below.

[image]